# template insertion in a editor

Tags: javascript, html, templates, tinymce-4

## Describing a scenario:

I am going through the code mentioned below.B asically I am trying to figure out how to program so that
when a user clicks on "Use Template" button , it gets inserted into an editor. 
Page 1:
There are lot of templates present
When a user clicks on the "Use Template" button on , it gets inserted into an editor that is present in 
the next page (Page 2).

Please find the code snippet below for the first two templates I am going through:

```
<div id="templatesWrap">
    <div class="template" data-templatelocation="templateone" data-templatename="Template ONE" data-templateid="" >
     <div class="templateContainer">
     <span>
      <a href="https://app.abc.com/pqr/core/compose/message/create?token=c1564e8e3cd11bc4t546b587jan31&amp;sMessageTemplateId=templateone&amp;sHubId=&amp;goalComplete=200" title="Use Template">
<img class="thumbnail" src="templatefiles/thumbnail_010.jpg" alt="templateone">
    </a>
    </span>
        <div class="templateName">Template ONE</div>
                <p>
        <a href="https://app.abc.com/pqr/core/compose/message/create?token=c1564e8e3cd11bc4t546b587jan31&amp;sMessageTemplateId=templateone&amp;sHubId=&amp;goalComplete=200" title="Use Template" class="button secondary">Use Template</a>
                </p>
        </div>
    </div>




  <div class="template" data-templatelocation="templatetwo" data-templatename="Template TWO" data-templateid="" >
    <div class="templateContainer">
    <span>
     <a href="https://app.abc.com/pqr/core/compose/message/create?token=c1564e8e3cd11bc4t546b587jan31&amp;sMessageTemplateId=templatetwo&amp;sHubId=&amp;goalComplete=200" title="Use Template">
    <img class="thumbnail" src="templatefiles/thumbnail_011.jpg" alt="templatetwo">
    </a>
    </span>
    <div class="templateName">Template TWO</div>
    <p>
    <a href="https://app.abc.com/pqr/core/compose/message/create?token=c1564e8e3cd11bc4t546b587jan31&amp;sMessageTemplateId=templatetwo&amp;sHubId=&amp;goalComplete=200" title="Use Template" class="button secondary">Use Template</a>
    </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And so on ....

How does the link `"https://app.abc.com/pqr/core/compose/message/create?token=c1564e8e3cd11bc4t546b587jan31&amp;sMessageTemplateId=templatetwo&amp;sHubId=&amp;goalComplete=200"` is inserting the template into the editor which is located on the next page? I haven't understood the token part and lot's of ID's present in the link
which I think are thereason behind inserting the template.

Has anyone come across such link before? Please advise.

Thanks

**MORE CLARIFICATIONS:**

Thanks for your answer.It did help me somewhat. I have few more questions:

Basically, I am using TinyMCE 4.0.8 version as my editor. The templates, I am using are from here:
https://github.com/mailchimp/email-blueprints/blob/master/templates/2col-1-2-leftsidebar.html

Some questions based on "Tivie" answer.

1) As you can see in the code for `"2col-1-2-leftsidebar.html "` it's not defined inside `<div>` tags unlike you defined it in `<div>` tags. Do you think that I can still
use it using `"2col-1-2-leftsidebar.html "` name?

2)I believe,for explanation purpose, you have included

```
`"<div contenteditable="true" id="myEditor">replaced stuff</div>`
 and 

<button id="btn">Load TPL</button>
<script>
$("#btn").click(function() {
    $("#myEditor").load("template.html");
});
</script>
```

in the same page. Am I right? ( I understand you were trying to make an educated guess here, hence
just asking :) )

In my case, I have a separate page, where I have written code for buttons just like you wrote in editor.html like the following:
`<button id="btn">Load TPL</button>`. My button is defined inside `<div class="templateContainer">`.
Also, my templates are defined in a separate folder. So, I will have to grab the content(HTML Template), from
that folder and then insert into TinyMCE 4.08 editor. (Looks like two step process). Could you elaborate
on how should I proceed here?

**More Question As of Dec 27**

I have modifier my code for the template as follows:

```
 <div class="templateName">Template ONE</div>
                <p>
        <a href="Here I have mentioned URL to next page where TinyMCE editor is mentioned" class="button secondary" id = "temp1">Use Template</a>
                </p>
```

Please note, I have added an additional id attribute for the following purpose.

If I go by the answer mentioned in the Tivia's post, is the following correct?

```
<script>
$("#temp1").click(function() {
    $("#sTextBody").load("FolderURL/template.html");
});
</script>
```

My editor is defined like the following on Page 2 (Editor Page).

```
<div class="field">

 <textarea id="sTextBody" name="sTextBody" style="width:948px; max-width:948px; height: 70%"></textarea>
</div>
```

I am confused, like, the script tag I have defined is in Page 1 where I have defined all the template related code
and the Page 2(Editor) page is a different page. It's simply taking me to Editor page (Page 2) and hence not working.

Please advise where I am wrong.
Thanks

**MORE QUESTIONS AS of Jan 2**

The problem Iam facing is as follows. Basically, for first template , I have the following code.

**Code  Snippet #1** where "Use "Template" button is present:

```
<div class="templateName">Template ONE</div>
                <p>
        <a href="Here I have mentioned URL to next page where TinyMCE editor is mentioned" class="button secondary" id = "temp1">Use Template</a>
                </p>
```

And the function suggested in the answer is as follows:

**Code Snippet #2** where Editor is present:

```
<script>
$("#temp1").click(function() {
    $("#sTextBody").load("FolderURL/template.html");
});
</script>
```

Since, I believe I first need to reach to that page after user clicks on "Use Template" button, where the editor is located, I have defined Code Snippet #1 on Page 1 and have defined the Code Snippet #2 and  `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` as the very first two script tags in the Page 2 ( Editor Page). But still when I click on "User Template" button on Page 1, it's just letting me to next page and not loading the template into the editor.

Am I doing something wrong here? Please advise.

P.S. The problem I feel is somehow the click function on Page 2 is not getting activated with the `temp1` id button mentioned on Page 1.

Thanks

Comment: Well, it's hard for us to say much without knowing anything about the API that this link is pointing at. I can guess that goalComplete=200 means to return status code 200 if goalComplete occurs, but that's not particularly helpful. More details?

Comment: The Code Snippet #2 must be in the same page where the template will be inserted

Comment: @Tivie I have handled that issue by passing the id to second page. I believe the `$.load()` isn't working and I need to use tinyMCE 4.X functions to insert the content, by any chance you have any idea regarding this?

Comment: I'm sorry, apart from the link I posted on my answer, I do not know the TinyMCE API well enough to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Well, one can only guess without having access to the page itself (and it's source code). I can, however, make an educated guess on how it works.

The URL params follows a pattern. First you have a token that is equal in all templates. This probably means the token does not have any relevance to the template mechanism itself. Maybe it's an authentication token or something. Not relevant though.

Then you have the template identification (templateOne, templateTwo, etc...) followed by a HubId that is empty. Lastly you have a goalComplete=200 which might correspond to the HTTP success code 200 (OK).

---

Based on this, my guess would be that they are probably using AJAX on the background, to fetch those templates from the server. Then, via JScript, those templates are inserted into the editor box itself.

Using JQuery, something like this is trivial. here's an example:

**template.html**

```
<div>
    <h1>TEST</h1>
    <span>This is a template</span>
</div>
```

**editor.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div contenteditable="true" id="myEditor">
    replaced stuff
</div>
<button id="btn">Load TPL</button>
<script>
$("#btn").click(function() {
    $("#myEditor").load("template.html");
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

## Edit:

1) Well, since those templates are quite complex and include CSS, you probably want to keep them separated from you editor page (or the template's CSS will mess up your page's css).
However, since you're using TinyMCE, it comes with a template manager built in, so you probably want to use that. Check this link here [http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:templates](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3atemplates) for documentation.

2) I think 1 answers your question but, just in case, my method above works for any page in any directory, provided it lives on the same domain. Example:

```
<script>
$("#btn").click(function() {
    $("#myEditor").load("someDirectory/template.html");
});
</script>
```

I recomend you check this page for the specifics on using TinyMCE [http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:templates](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3atemplates)

## EDIT2:

Let me explain the above code:

```
$("#btn").click(function() { });
```

This basically tells the browser to run the code inside the brackets when you click the element with an id="btn"

```
$("#myEditor").load("someDirectory/template.html");
```

This is an AJAX request ([check the documentation here](http://api.jquery.com/load/)). It grabs the contents of `someDirectory/template.html` and places them inside the element whose id="myEditor"

Comment: Thansk for your answer. Could you please answer my more questions in my updated question?

Comment: Thanks. I am already using Inbuilt Template option of TinyMCE but in addition to that I want to use my own approach as well because later on I want to specify a "blank template" option and "saving template" functionality for the user.

Comment: Could you please check my attempt on my edited question. Thanks

Comment: @Jack  see if this helps

Comment: Thanks for very nice explanation. Could you please look at the problem I am facing ? I have updated my question under today's date. Thanks